# Cannot solve the problem running project with MonoDevelop

Tags: ubuntu, monodevelop

I've just installed MonoDevelop on my Ubuntu 20.04 and have an error running test project:

> **Debugger operation failed**

> ApplicationName='/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server', CommandLine='--app-id mono.develop.idea2f83d0b35d44e09d67f33ce9074849', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file

I googled it and find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336129/error-when-trying-to-run-code-debugger-operation-failed-native-error-cannot-f) solution, so I ran it on my system, but it still not works.

Here's console output after running bash script:

```
/Documents/C#$ sudo ./script.sh
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘gnome-terminal’: File exists
---------------------
Folder contents: 
gnome-terminal-server
---------------------
gnome-terminal-server
ln: failed to create symbolic link './gnome-terminal-server': File exists
```

And this is my script:

```
cd ../..
cd /usr/lib

sudo mkdir gnome-terminal
cd gnome-terminal
echo "---------------------"
echo "Folder contents: "
ls
echo "---------------------"
ls
sudo ln -sv /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
```

I'm quite new to Linux so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-end-of-monodevelop-80b383dab34b No matter what you plan to do with MonoDevelop, switch to an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do.

first change **'cd ../..'** to '**cd'** on script.
There is not much difference in changes, but **'cd'** command bring you to root directory whatever location you at and run.

Second thing,  **'ln: failed to create symbolic link './gnome-terminal-server': File exists'** seem that soft link has been existed.

So, if you want to run again this script, then remove directory **'gnome-terminal'** and try to run again. Before run the script, please open the new terminal to ensure the changes has been made on system. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (also found the solution you googled and did not work for me either). I solved it by uninstalling the default gnome terminal and installing the termit variant instead. Now my Monodevelop IDE runs the code correctly.